# How to use a SRV record to point to port other than 80

Tags: http, dns, cname, srv-record

I have this Route 53 record in the AWS console:

```
Type: SRV - Service Locator
```

And the value is:

```
1 10 4000 ec2-54-xx-xx-131.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

so I was hoping that if I hit:

```
monitoring.x.teros.io
```

that it would reach:

```
ec2-54-xx-xx-131.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4000
```

but I am getting:

> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

anyone know how to use a SRV record to point to some endpoint that is not on port 80?

Answer (score 2):

The 4000 in the `SRV` data of `1 10 4000 ec2-54-xx-xx-131.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` is the port. However, `SRV` records are only good if applications use them... and browsers do not.

So it seems you are in this case (your question is too vague and not really related to programming, but the error message you quote seems to come from a well known browser), and hence no `SRV` records will ever help you.

Comment: Based on https://curl.haxx.se/docs/todo.html#SRV_and_URI_DNS_records support for `SRV` records seem to be on the TODO list hence not existing now. If you really need to do that today you will need some shell plumbing, basically first resolving the `SRV` record yourself then injecting the result in `curl`.

Comment: workaround to using awk in curl command `curl http://$(dig +short {HOST} srv | awk '{printf "%s:%s\n",$4,$3}')`

Answer (score 0):

`SRV` records are not supported by many command line programs.   To handle them, I made this simple tool [`srv-plz`](https://github.com/neomantra/srv-plz) which resolves `SRV` records and allows injecting them into commands.

For your example `monitoring.x.teros.io`, you could fully resolve that and `curl` the ultimate `ip:port` with this command:

```
# print for debugging 
$ srv-plz -r -c monitoring.x.eros.io

# inject it into a curl command
$ srv-plz -r -c monitoring.x.eros.io -- curl http://%SRV%/health
```

You can template the `SRV` record output to fit the specific check you are testing.  It is written in Go so available on many platforms.